# Is using distro-bundled LAMP the best choice?

Tags: installation, apache-2.4, lamp

I am wondering - it is better to use distribution-provided LAMP stack or install it on my own?
I mean, is it ok just to use `apt-get install apache2 (...)` or it is better to just download the software, unpack it in your own directory?

The definition of better - it is hard topic, after all. 
Those LAMP stack is to be placed as one of many services on the same machine, open to world by some reverse-proxy (nginx?).
I may want to end up using two or three different instances of Apache2 (shall I?).
I like to manageability of applications contained within simple directory. Puff, and they are gone. I also think I may easily just create new user and restrict it to one and only one directory.

On the other hand, as a newbie I have a feeling that packages managers prepared everything in more secure way, thought about many problems I probably can't even think of. It is also much easier to keep up to date with just one command.

My question is - is using distro-default packages the way to go in my case?

Comment: The answer to this question is so highly dependent on your individual specific use case that there is no good answer. It may even change from one project to another.

Comment: One word only: Yes. (unless it's absolutely impossible with prepackaged stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to sound patronising, but as you state, you're a newbie and I'd recommend a newbie to keep things as simple as possible and keep with the distro packages and capabilities. I personally recommend against running multiple instances of Apache on a server, if you need that kind of security, consider things like Xen, Kvm or even Docker.

That said, I work for a sysadmin company and we generally try to stay as true to a distro as possible. That's the easiest way to make use of the solutions a maintainer has already provided. But I admit, sometimes finding those solutions can be a bit of a challenge. Serverfault can help with that, though!