# Best practice installation of Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, best-practices

When installing Docker on an Ubuntu machine, there are several competing ways to install it, that seem to be the best practice according to someone. Specifically, you can install according to the guide on [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/), which I assume is the best practice according to docker, or you can install the docker.io package using the apt package manager, which I would again assume to be the best practice according to Canonical and the Ubuntu team.

I initially suspected that the Ubuntu version would be more up to date on security updates, but as docker are simply adding a repository to the package manager it's not like they can't just put the security update there for you to get at a moments notice.
So currently I'm just assuming that the Ubuntu version would be less up to date but more thoroughly tested. If that's the only difference I think that in production and other sensitive environments you would prefer the Ubuntu version unless there is a feature in the newer release that you need to have. I've also read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/670752/is-using-distro-bundled-lamp-the-best-choice) that the default is to using the packages given by the distro, but the way docker install it as a repo rather than just a package from a site, seems to mitigate at least some of the issues with installing from an external provider.
Which one is better and why?

Comment: Here are 2 links that might help you balance the risks and make a decision: https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2018/07/04/docker-io-debian-package-back-to-life/ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678382/9401096

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks! Would you like to make an answer out of that or would you suggest I close the question as a dup. of a question from a sibling site?